# How to prevent new window/tab opening after form post

Tags: html, forms, post

I have a form submission like:

```
<form target="_blank" id="discussionForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<%=discussionURL%>">
```

Then I have a Submit button at the end.  This works, and it posts to my db, but it opens a new tab with the url of the service that I'm using to post to the db.  I don't want that new tab to open.  I tried playing around with different targets, but I thought _blank would work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove:  `target="_blank"`

Comment: If I don't use target="_blank", it replaces the current tab, it doesn't start a new one.  I don't want it opening anything.

Comment: How will the user know that they have successfully submitted the form?

Answer (score 7):

Remove `target` attribute and it should be fine.

`target="_blank"` actually means it should open in a new tab/window.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target) (please always read the docs first)

Comment: if I don't use target="_blank", it replaces the current tab with a blank screen (my ReST service's response).  I don't want it opening anything.  thoughts?

Comment: @ZachLucas You haven't said what was the intended behaviour. In this case, you could catch the `submit` event for the form, prevent submitting, and post the data using AJAX in the background. Or redirect the form to a hidden `iframe` - this can be done with the `target` attribute, check the docs I linked :). `form`s work like this by default, they open the page in the `action`, so you have to either prevent it (JS) or find a way around (iframe).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this attribute when you want to display that what the submission of this form returned but on an other `page`/`container` `_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename`, I suppose it was build back then when people were writing markup with the `frames` to give it a kind of html support, nowadays it's very bizare to use/need it.

"The target attribute specifies a name or a keyword that indicates where to display the response that is received after submitting the form." - [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In the case that someone does not have a `target` attribute, they may add the `onclick` and the `onkeypress` attributes with the following JS as shown below:

`<form action="/Account/Login" class="form" method="post" onclick="return event.shiftKey !== true;" onkeypress="return !(event.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey);">
</form>`

The `onclick` filters out any 'shift + click'. The `onkeypress` prevents 'shift + enter'.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a solution to one of the [thread](https://jsfiddle.net/5cbx3yj9/)  here :

Recently I got this scenario and researched a lot to find the hack/solution.

**Solution** - If you can put a window names and refer same every time, then browser will make sure to open new tab if not opened already, otherwise it will just refresh the window.

Example snippet: [Demo JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5cbx3yj9/)

```
<form id="myForm" action="<URL>" method="POST" target="_blank" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
    <button type="submit" id="btnTest"> Submit</button>
</form>


<script>
var target_popup = function(form) {
    window.open('',//URL should be blank so that it will take form attributes.
                'UniqueWindowName', //window name
                'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
    form.target = 'UniqueWindowName';
}
</script>
```

Please refer my [blog](https://pradeep-dani.blogspot.com/2018/11/make-html-form-to-not-open-new-window.html) for more details